# Objectify - Partial indexing of a Map<> object based on key name

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dictionary, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am trying to do a partial indexing of a Map, with a condition based on the key name of the map.

My goal is to index only the `A` key, because I know that I will query only on that.

Here is a simple demo code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "1");
map.put("B", "2");

MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
mainClass.mapIndexed = map;
mainClass.mapUnindexed = map;

ObjectifyService.register(MainClass.class);
ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entities(mainClass);
```

And the test class

```
@Entity
public class MainClass {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Unindex
    Map<String, String> mapUnindexed;

    @Index
    Map<String, String> mapIndexed;
}
```

As you can see from the result, both `A` and `B` keys are indexed, but I want to index only the `A` key.
[image]

I already know that Objectify provided the concept of [partial-indexing](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries#Partial_Indexes), but it seems that I can use this only on the entire map (index the entire map or don't index the map at all).

Is there a way to index only some keys of the map based on custom conditions? (like the name of the key)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Unfortunately, there is not currently an easy way to do this; please file an enhancement request in Github.

If this is absolutely critical to address immediately (ie, you're burning big $ in the datastore), you can copy the `EmbeddedMapTranslatorFactory`, change the save() code, and enable this new version on the field using the `@Translate` annotation.

Or, if you're feeling adventurous and want to submit a PR, the important change is to pass a `Path` into the `If<?,?>` methods.